# Laravel request attribute add not appeard

Tags: php, laravel

I create a middleware that will add some few more fields into a request compared to origional like so.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $profile = Authentication::profile();
    $request->attributes->add(['dataUser' => $profile]);
    return $next($request);
}
```

And then in my controller, I dump all the request params with this code.

```
$request = Request::all();
```

But when I `var_dump($request)` the `dataUser` field is not exists, but strangelly when I call `Request::get('dataUser')` then it still returns the value.

I know I can use `Request::get('dataUser')` for solved but I just want to use `$request = Request::all();` instead of use multiple `static` class.

What mistake have I made?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add param to request like:

```
$request->request->add(['variable', 'value']);
```

Comment: what you are trying to do, it will add that new variable in `attribute` object whereas you are getting values from `$request->request` object

Comment: you can check using `dd($request);`